# Why is my script not being able to kick a user?

Tags: lua, roblox

This script is designed so that when you say "!kick [user]" it kicks that user from the game. But, when I test it out, nothing happens with no errors in the output box. Whats going on?

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.Chatted:Connect(function(player,message)
        if player.Name == "playername" then
            local words = string.split(message," ")
            if string.lower(words[1]) == "!kick" then
                words[2]:Kick("You have been kicked.")
            end
        end
    end)
end)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason nothing is happening right now is because your very first check is failing. You have the parameters for the [Player.Chatted](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Player/Chatted) connection backwards. The message comes first and the recipient comes second. So what you've named `player` is actually the message and `if player.Name == "playername" then` is likely failing because strings don't have a Name property and `player.Name` is nil.

After that, the next issue you will run into is that after you've split the command into two parts, the second half of the command is still a string, and not a Player. So you need to find a Player with a matching name as the input string.

Try something like this:

```lua
local Players = game.Players

local function findPlayerByName(name)
    -- escape if nothing is provided
    if name == nil then
        return nil
    end

    -- check if any players match the name provided
    local allPlayers = Players:GetPlayers()
    for _, player in ipairs(allPlayers) do
        if player.Name == name or string.lower(player.Name) == name then
            return player
        end
    end

    -- couldn't find any players that matched
    return nil
end

-- define all the players that can use commands
local admins = {
    ["playername"] = true,
}

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.Chatted:Connect(function(message, recipient)
        if admins[player.Name] then
            local words = string.split(message, " ")
            local cmd = string.lower(words[1])
            if cmd == "!kick" then
                local playerName = words[2]
                local targetPlayer = findPlayerByName(playerName)
                if targetPlayer then
                    targetPlayer:Kick("You have been kicked.")
                end
            end
        end
    end)
end)
```